# Split huge mysql insert into multiple files suggestions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Huge mysql dump I need to import, I managed to split the 3gig file by table insert, one of the table inserts is 600MBs, I want to split it into 100 MB files. So my question is: is there a script or easy way to split a 600MB INSERT statement into multiple 100MB inserts without having to open the file (as this kills my pc).

I tried SQLDumpSplitter but this does not help.

here is the reason I cannot just run the 600MB file:

[MYSQL import response 'killed'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581809/mysql-import-response-killed)

Please help

Comment: Check this solution for Windows/linux:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132902/how-do-i-split-the-output-from-mysqldump-into-smaller-files/30988416#30988416

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily open a file of 1GB on Textpad software. User this software to open the file and split your queries as what you want.

Link for downloading TextPad software [***TextPad***](http://www.textpad.com/download/)

Comment: This is the solution I used

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, easiest way to split files is [`split -l N`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/split) - split to pieces `N` lines each.

On Windows, I've had pretty good luck with [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) - it works well with huge files.